# Why is "" necessary for this for loop to run?

Tags: javascript

The code is below -

```
for (let n = 1; n <= 100; n++) {
  let output = "";
  if (n % 3 == 0) output += "Fizz";
  if (n % 5 == 0) output += "Buzz";
  console.log(output || n);
}
```

If I do not have let output = "" the code will not run.  Why is that statement required?

Comment: I think because you need the variable declared before you can assign to it

Comment: Well if you don't declare the variable `output`, the statement `output += "…"` that tries to use it will throw an exception. Your [developer tools](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) should show you this error.

Comment: This will not work as you expect, you need to put `output` outside of the loop. Also, you can just run it without output defined and read the error.

Comment: The code runs now and outputs fizz, buzz, and fizzbuzz while the loop runs.  I just don't understand the need for the output variable.

Comment: @lbu Actually the code currently does work just fine. Notice that the `console.log` is inside the loop as well.

Comment: @TommyLonergan Well you hardly can do it without if you don't want to repeat `console.log` statements

Comment: What does this have to do with scope? It doesn't matter if `output` is defined inside or outside the loop, the matter is that it needs to be defined. It seems OP doesn't understand the need for defining the variable before concatenating

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have written output +="Fuzz" which means output = output +"Fizz". If you didn't initialize the output code will not understand what to took for output(right after=) and give you error. You can initialize the output (let) before loop.

Answer (score 0):

because without `let output=""` the variable `output` is undefined, so your code will crash with the error `output is not defined`

Comment: why do I define output as a space though ""

Comment: you aren't defining it as a space, you're defining it as an empty string. You'd type `let output = " "` if you wanted to set it to a space. the reason you initialize it to an empty string, as opposed to, say just putting `let output` is because if you don't assign a value to your variable it is simply `undefined`. if you then append a string to your undefined variable with `output += fizz`, you will now have a string that reads `undefinedfizz`